# How to mock function using jest.fn()

Tags: jestjs

The jest document says, `There are two ways to get your hands on mock functions: Either by require()ing a mocked component (via jest.mock('moduleName')) or by explicitly requesting one from jest.fn() in your test:`

So I am trying mocking a function thinking whenever a test makes a call to the `minus` function, it executes the mocked function and returns `10` instead of `a*b` but it's not working the way I thought.

**app.js:**

```js
function add(a, b) {
  return multiply(a, b) + b;
}

function multiply(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}

module.exports = add;
```

**add-test.js**

```js
const add = require('./add');
describe('add', () => {
  it('should add two numbers', () => {
    const multiply = jest.fn((a, b) => {10})
    expect(add(1, 2)).toBe(12);
  });
});
```

Note: If I change `expect(add(1, 2)).toBe(12);` to `expect(add(1, 2)).toBe(4);` the test will pass, but I want to mock `multiply` and return 10. So when I actually call made to `multiply` function then it should invoke mocked function and not real implementation.

Comment: You have to make sure you are mocking the function that is actually called in `app.js`, right now what you have is just a mock function assigned to a variable called `multiply`, but jest doesn't know that you mean to mock the `multiply` function in `app.js`

Comment: @MaxMillington how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change the structure of `app.js` slightly to test this the way you want.

You can either extract `multiply()` into its own file like this:

**mulitiply.js**

```js
function multiply(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}
```

**app.js**

```js
function add(a, b) {
 return multiply(a, b) + b;
}
```

**add.test.js**

```js
const add = require('./add');
const multiply = require('./multiply');
jest.mock('multiply', () => jest.fn(a, b) => 10)

describe('add', () => {
  it('adds the numbers', () => {
    expect(add(1, 2)).toBe(12);
  });
});
```

or change the implementation to be something like this:

**add.js**

```js
function add(multiply) {
   multiply()
}
```

**add.test.js**

```js
const add = require('./add');

describe('add', () => {
  it('adds the numbers', () => {
    const multiply = jest.fn(a,b) => 10;
    expect(add(multiply(1, 2)).toBe(12);
  });
});
```

Comment: `jest.mock('multiply', ()=> jest.fn(a, b) => {10})`, this line seems to be invalid js. Can you explain a bit more what is happening in that line?

Comment: updated the syntax, you will be able to see it once it's approved.